SSIS Package Completes all Tasks but encounters a time out error updating the SSIDB catalog
SQL Server 2016 13.0.7050.2
I have an SSIS Package that uses a Foreach Loop Container to execute several (86) other SSIS Packages. The entire process completes successfully and should exit as successful and be done, however very frequently (~90% of the time) instead of exiting, the package gets a Timeout error. I assume there is some post execution logging and clean up that is taking place under the hood of SSIS and that's what is timing out. I am guessing that for two reasons. 1) When the package is successful or when it fails all the messages are the same but when it fails it gets one extra error message indicating the Timeout and it is exactly 90 seconds after the whole package finishes. 2) The message source is indicating that the step generating the error message is "Transact-SQL stored procedure" There is no task or command in any of the SSIS (even using notepad++ and searching their XML) by that name.
The following screen shot is how the history looks when things work.

The following screen shot is ow the history looks when things don't work. It shows that everything works up to the exact same point but then 90 seconds after, it gets the timeout error.

That leaves two questions that I can't find an answer to (and really want to avoid setting up traces/extended events to reverse engineer what SSIS is doing).

What is SSIS doing at the end of the package that would timeout?
Can the timeout setting be increased, not referring to timeout settings in the connection managers but the setting that controls how long SSIS will wait while trying to update its internal tables in the SSISDB (at the very least I could increase/decrease to confirm the post processing theory)?

We tried setting all connection strings in the connection managers with CommandTimeout=0 and MultipleActiveReslutSets=False (OLE DB Connections to SQL Server) It had no effect (this was expected and part of ruling out the package components as opposed to the internals of SSIS)
Run packages individually, this works but is not what is needed but does help re-enforce suspicion that this is caused by contention with the SSIS internal post processing as opposed to something in one of the packages.
This package is a replacement of an existing package that did a "Truncate and Re-Load" of data across 86 tables. It's being converted to detect changes instead of deleting all the data first. The original package didn't hit this error and was a single package that had many data flow tasks to handle each table. Another question would be, is it worth converting the new process to be one package with many data flows instead of breaking it into multiple packages. (Without knowing what SSIS is doing post process this is hard to justify since I don't know if it will do any good.)
